# How to debug name error in the python code

Tags: python

I am trying to make a login system but what stopping me is the Name error which I could not debug

```
know = input("Do you want to signup or log-in \n for signup  enter (s) \n for log-in enter (l):")
if know == "s":
    user_signup = input("Enter username:")
    user_signup2 = input("Enter password: ")
    user_signup3 = int(input("Enetr Age:"))
theinfo = [user_signup , user_signup2,user_signup3]

if know =="l":
    login = input("Enter username: ")
    user_login2 = input("Enter password:")
elif login in theinfo and user_login2 in theinfo:
    print("Log in seccefull")
elif login not in theinfo or user_login2 not in theinfo:
    print("username or password incorect")
```

and this is the error that I find:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\code\gg\.vscode\login.py", line 11, in <module>
    elif login in theinfo and user_login2 in theinfo:
NameError: name 'login' is not defined
```

Comment: If `know` is not "l", then `login` is never defined. Hence your error.

Comment: thanks man appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
know = input("Do you want to signup or log-in \n For signup  enter (s) \n For log-in enter (l):")

if know == "s":
    user_signup = input("Enter username:")
    user_signup2 = input("Enter password: ")
    user_signup3 = int(input("Enter Age:"))

theinfo = [user_signup, user_signup2, user_signup3]

print()
know = input("Do you want to signup or log-in \n For signup  enter (s) \n For log-in enter (l):")
print()

if know == "l":
    login = input("Enter username: ")
    user_login2 = input("Enter password:")

    if login in theinfo and user_login2 in theinfo:
        print("Log in successful")
    elif login not in theinfo or user_login2 not in theinfo:
        print("username or password incorrect")
```

`NameError` means that the **variable is not defined earlier**. The way you set up the condition for your program is wrong. I have corrected the program.

Answer (score 0):

With if / elif, zero or one of the sections of code will be read.  Let's look at your if / elif / elif code:

```
if know =="l":
    login = input("Enter username: ")
    user_login2 = input("Enter password:")
elif login in theinfo and user_login2 in theinfo:
    print("Log in seccefull")
elif login not in theinfo or user_login2 not in theinfo:
    print("username or password incorect")
```

If the user enters 'l', then login is set.  However, the next two "elif" sections will be skipped. You can fix that like this:

```
if know =="l":
    login = input("Enter username: ")
    user_login2 = input("Enter password:")
    if login in theinfo and user_login2 in theinfo:
        print("Log in seccefull")
    elif login not in theinfo or user_login2 not in theinfo:
        print("username or password incorect")
```

So, that answers the question.  However, the code will still not work as expectecd for several reasons. However, you are primarily missing a credentials list to store your full set of users. You do not have credentials for existing users, so you cannnot check the username and password of returning users.  Nor can you save the credentials of new users to the list of existing users.

```
know = input('Do you want to signup or log-in \n for signup, enter (s) \n for log-in, enter (l): ').upper()

# Start with a fetch of existing users.
# I am hard-coding users to keep the example simple.  
# Don't do this in your actual code.  You can use something
# like a simple file (though you should not store clear text
# text passwords in a text file. 
# https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp
credentials = [['Phil', 'my_Password', 37], ['jose', 'espanol', 19]]

the_info = []

if know == 'S':
    user_signup = input('Enter username:')
    user_signup2 = input('Enter password: ')
    user_signup3 = int(input('Enter age:'))
    the_info = [user_signup , user_signup2, user_signup3]
    # The next line save the new user in memory.  
    # Add code to save the info to a file or database. 
    credentials += the_info
    print('Thanks for signing up.')
elif know =='L':
    login = input('Enter username: ')
    user_login2 = input('Enter password: ')
    success = False
    for credential in credentials:
        if login.upper() == credential[0].upper() and user_login2 == credential[1]:
            the_info = credential
            break
    if len(the_info) > 0 :
        print(f'Log in successful.  Hello {the_info[0]}')
    else:
        print('username or password incorrect.')

print(f'User info: {the_info}')
```